# Using PWM to communicate between ATTiny85s

Tags: pwm, attiny

**Some background:** I am putting together a display to teach children about how neural circuits work.  I am making a group of 'blocks' (each of which contains an ATTiny85, an indicator LED, and input/output wires) that can be connected in different configurations to represent different circuit motifs.

**The problem:** I am trying to use PWM to communicate between the ATTiny85s.  My original idea, simply reading input PWM signals with `analogRead` and generating a PWM output with `analogWrite`, worked fine while all the ATTiny85s were running off a 5V power supply from an Arduino.  However, now that I've switched to using a 4.5V battery pack for each ATTiny85, the PWM communication no longer works.

I expected the PWM outputs to change somewhat (given that `HIGH` is now limited to 4.5V), but what I am finding is that the output values (when read into an Arduino using `analogRead` OR `pulseIn`) now jump around hugely (e.g. `pulseIn` read out between 50 and 15000 from PWM output `analogWrite(250)`).  Even averaging over up to 1000 pulses doesn't do much to smooth out the value.

Am I missing something?

Comment: PWM is digital (`analogWrite` is badly named since there is nothing analogue about it). You'll need to filter (e.g. RC low pass) the PWM signal to get an analogue voltage.

Comment: I don't need an actual analog voltage, I just need some way for the ATTiny85s to communicate in different configurations.  The `analogRead` to get the PWM input was a bit of a cheat, but I'm having the same problem using `pulseIn`.

Comment: You will have to explain your signal protocol better. Do you just want to detect whether there's a PWM output or not, or does the PWM actually contain data? If so, how is it encoded?

Comment: @Dampmaskin - The PWM is encoding the level of 'activity' for each block, so higher duty cycle = more activity.  (The 'activity' is calculated on each ATTiny based on things like input from a potentiometer, or input from another ATTiny.)  I need some way of communicating this degree of activity between the ATTiny85s (so effectively an "analog" signal), but I can change how I'm encoding/transmitting it if there's a better way.

Comment: Have you got a shared ground between all your nodes? Ie negative of all batteries shorted. If each ATTiny has its own battery they will all have different ADC references based on their battery state.

Comment: As Tom Carpenter said, you should low pass filter the PWM so that it becomes a stable voltage. The ADC can't make sense of raw PWM, and I have no idea why it seemed to work for you at 5V.

Comment: @Colin__s - I don't have a shared ground, so that could be an issue.  Would that still be a problem just reading the pulse length (`pulseIn`) though?

Comment: @fminl Yes. The pulse is only high relative to something. If the reference is different on the different boards they can't know if the signal is high or low.

Comment: @Colin__s - Yep, looks like that was my problem.  When I join up the ground pins I get a stable read.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember, voltage is a difference between two nodes, not a single absolute value. :)

Answer (score -2):

The analog read should yield the same adv number if the reference is set to vdd.

Pulsein should also give the same results.

The issue is likely your code or wiring.